# Three.js Updating DataTextures with a renderTarget's image data

Tags: three.js, rendertarget

I am working on a motion detection program in `Three.js` which uses the difference between the current and previous frame. For now, before the subtraction, the current and the previous frame are both blurred using a `Three.EffectComposer` each.

**The main problem is**: Instead of having to blur the previous frame again, I want to use the previously blurred "current" frame as the texture in the subtraction process.

The closest I have managed to do is by using the function below to update the image.data of the `Three.DataTexture`. It was used in the `render()`-function after the Blurring composer is rendered, but before the subtraction is rendered. 
Both of them were rendered to the screen with `Three.CopyShader`.

```js
function getData(image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    return  new Uint8Array(context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height).data);
}
```

Where the “image” is the `renderer.domElement`. This method feels quite inefficient and I needed to render the Blur-pass to the screen, which caused the result to flicker.

*Edit 1*  The current code is shown below, it blurs the current and previous images and then calculates the difference. The `animate()`-function is the point of interest.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Three.js Webcam Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/three.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Effect composer scripts -->
    <script src = "postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
    <script src = "postprocessing/MaskPass.js"></script>
    <script src = "postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
    <script src = "postprocessing/TexturePass.js"></script>
    <script src = "postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
    <script src = "postprocessing/SavePass.js"></script>

    <script src = "shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
    <script src = "shaders/ColorifyShader.js"></script>
    <script src = "shaders/DilationShader.js"></script>
    <script src = "shaders/ErosionShader.js"></script>
    <script src = "shaders/HorizontalBlurShader.js"></script>
    <script src = "shaders/VerticalBlurShader.js"></script>
    <script src = "shaders/BlendShader.js"></script>
    <script src = "shaders/passThroughShader.js"></script>
    <script src = "shaders/framediffShader.js"></script>
    <script src = "shaders/PawaskarPostShader.js"></script>
    <!-- ----------------------- -->

    <script src="lib/Projector.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/webcam.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/perspective.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/rStats.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/rStats.extras.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootswatch.com/lumen/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Motion Detection (in progress)</h1>
        <p>Press P to print the current frame</p>
<div id="WebGL-output">
</div>

<div id="camera" class="camera">
    <div class="label"></div>
    <video id="theVideo" autoplay width="640" height="480" class="webcam"></video>
    <canvas id="theCanvas"  width="640" height="480" class="hidden"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    var SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;

    var values = {
        detectmotion: true,
        softness: 0.17,
        threshold: 0.11,
        color: "#ffae23",
        usecolor: false,
        postprocess: false,
        postprocessmethod: 0,
        preprocess: true,
        detectedges: false,
        framedifference: false,
        binarydifference: false,
        bufferlength: 1
    };

    var stats, container, video, renderer, currTexture, uniforms, camera, scene, prevTexture, prevTexture2, prevTexture3, prevTextureBuffer = [], bufferLenght,
        videoContext,
        prevTime;
    var rS, glS, tS;
    var postProcessFilters = [];
    var prepScene, prepRenderTarget, prepComposer, prepPrevComposer, hBlur, vBlur, temporalShader, prevTemporalShader, prevBlur;
    var modelScene, modelRenderTarget, modelComposer, passShader;
    var subtractScene, subtractRenderTarget,subtractComposer, subtractShader;
    //GUI variables
    var gui, cPostProcessMethod, doPostProcess = false;
    var frameNumber;
    /** TEST **/
    var BlurSave;

    function init(){

        frameNumber = 0;
        /* INIT */

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        camera = new THREE.Camera();
        scene.add(camera);

        webcam.updateSources(function(s){
            webcam.start('theVideo',s[0]);
        });

        var size = SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT;

        video = document.getElementById( 'theVideo' );
        videoContext = document.getElementById('theCanvas').getContext('2d');

        //The textures
        currTexture = new THREE.DataTexture([],SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        prevTexture = new THREE.DataTexture([],SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        prevBlur = new THREE.DataTexture([], SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        currTexture.minFilter = prevTexture.minFilter = prevBlur.minFilter=  THREE.LinearFilter;

        prevTime = -1;

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        renderer.domElement.width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
        renderer.domElement.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
        renderer.autoClear = false;
        document.body.insertBefore(renderer.domElement, document.body.childNodes[0]);

        uniforms = {
            currentTexture:   { type: "t", value: currTexture },
            mirrorImage:       { type: "i", value: 0}
        }

        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1);
        var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
            uniforms: uniforms,
            vertexShader: THREE.passThroughShader.vertexShader,
            fragmentShader: THREE.passThroughShader.fragmentShader

        } );

        // A plane with the current video context as texture
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
        mesh.material.depthTest = false;
        mesh.material.depthWrite = false;
        scene.add(mesh);

        // COPY SHADER, used to render the current context to the screen
        var effectCopy = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
        effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;

        /** Preprocess stage **/

        prepScene = new THREE.Scene();
        prepScene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff ) );
        prepScene.add(mesh) // add the current quad

        var renderTargetParameters = {minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBFormat, stencilBuffer: false};

        //blur shaders
        hBlur = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.HorizontalBlurShader);
        hBlur.uniforms["h"].value = 1 / SCREEN_WIDTH;
        hBlur.enabled = values['preprocess'];

        vBlur = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.VerticalBlurShader);
        vBlur.uniforms["v"].value = 1 / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
        vBlur.enabled = values['preprocess'];

        BlurSave = new THREE.SavePass(new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, renderTargetParameters));

        //preprocess scene render pass
        var renderModelPrep = new THREE.RenderPass(prepScene, camera);
        var prevPassShader1 = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.passThroughShader);
        prevPassShader1.uniforms["mirrorImage"].value = 1;

        //Preprocess of the current image
        //It is this prepComposer's rendertarget value I want to use in the next loop
        prepComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, renderTargetParameters));
        prepComposer.addPass(renderModelPrep);
        prepComposer.addPass(prevPassShader1);
        prepComposer.addPass(hBlur);
        prepComposer.addPass(vBlur);
        prepComposer.addPass(BlurSave);

        //
       // subtractComposer.addPass(effectCopy);

        //Preprocess of the previous image
        //Want to skip this stage
        var prevPassShader = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.passThroughShader, prevTexture);
        prevPassShader.uniforms["currentTexture"].value = prevTexture;
        prevPassShader.uniforms["mirrorImage"].value = 1;
        var prevBlurSave = new THREE.SavePass(new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, renderTargetParameters));

        prepPrevComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, renderTargetParameters));
        prepPrevComposer.addPass(renderModelPrep);
        prepPrevComposer.addPass(prevPassShader);
        prepPrevComposer.addPass(hBlur);
        prepPrevComposer.addPass(vBlur);
        prepPrevComposer.addPass(prevBlurSave);

        /**------------------**/

        /**---------------------------**/

        /** Background Subtraction stage **/

        subtractScene = new THREE.Scene();
        subtractScene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff ) );

        var renderTargetParameters3 = {minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, format: THREE.RGBAFormat, stencilBuffer: false};

        //Background Subtraction shaders
        subtractShader = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.framediffShader);
        subtractShader.uniforms['currentTexture'].value = BlurSave.renderTarget; // from the preprocess
        subtractShader.uniforms['previousTexture'].value = prevBlurSave.renderTarget; //modelled background

        //Background subtraction scene render pass
        var renderSubtract = new THREE.RenderPass(subtractScene, camera);

        //Background subtraction Composer
        subtractComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer, new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, renderTargetParameters3));
        subtractComposer.addPass(renderSubtract);
        subtractComposer.addPass(subtractShader);

        //subtractComposer.addPass(effectCopy2);

        /**------------------------------**/

        /** Postprocessing stage **/

        //Dilation
        var dilationFilter = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.DilationShader);
        dilationFilter.enabled = values['postprocess'];
        postProcessFilters.push(dilationFilter);
        //Erosion
        var erosionFilter = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.ErosionShader);
        erosionFilter.enabled = values['postprocess'];
        postProcessFilters.push(erosionFilter);

        //Pawaskar's postprocess filter
        var pawaskarFilter = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.PawaskarPostShader);
        pawaskarFilter.uniforms['threshold'].value = values['threshold'];
        pawaskarFilter.enabled = values['postprocess'];
        postProcessFilters.push(pawaskarFilter);

        subtractComposer.addPass(pawaskarFilter);

        //Opening
        subtractComposer.addPass(erosionFilter);
        subtractComposer.addPass(dilationFilter);
        //Closing
        subtractComposer.addPass(dilationFilter);
        subtractComposer.addPass(erosionFilter);

        //The final result rendered to the screen
        subtractComposer.addPass(effectCopy);

        /**----------------------**/

        animate();

    }

    function animate()
    {

        if(video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ){
            var time = video.currentTime;
            if(time !== prevTime){
                //Because a firefox bug when drawImage is used, need to catch NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE
                try {

                    videoContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT); //update the video

                    if(currTexture.image.data.length){

                        //var imgData = getData(renderer.domElement);
                        //var imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();

                       // var gl = renderer.getContext();
                        //gl.readPixels( 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, prevBlur.image.data );

                       //prevBlur.image.data = imgData;
                       // prevBlur.needsUpdate = true;

                        /** I want to update the prevBlur texture with the BlurSave.renderTarget! **/

                        prevTexture.image.data = currTexture.image.data;
                        prevTexture.needsUpdate = true; //updates the previous texture in the shader
                    }

                    currTexture.image.data = new Uint8Array(videoContext.getImageData(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT).data);
                    currTexture.needsUpdate = true; //updates the current texture in the shader
                    prevTime = time;

                }catch (e) {
                    if (e.name == "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE") {
                        console.error(e);
                    } else {
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        prepComposer.render(0.05);
        prepPrevComposer.render(0.05);
        subtractComposer.render(0.05);

        frameNumber++;
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

     function getData(image) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        return new Uint8Array(context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height).data);
    }


    function copyCanvas(e) {
        var imgData, imgNode;
        if (e.which !== 80) {
            return;
        } else {
            imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
        }
        // create a new image and add to the document
        imgNode = document.createElement("img");
        imgNode.src = imgData;
        document.body.appendChild(imgNode);
    }


    window.onload = init;

    window.addEventListener("keyup", copyCanvas);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

- How can I update the `prevBlur.image.data` with the current image data of the `BlurSave.rendertarget`?
- Are there any other way to update a shader's `Sampler2D` uniform with the value from a `WebGLRenderTarget`’s image data from a previous time-step?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is a bit general. Can you show a live example to demonstrate exactly what you are doing, and then ask a specific question about it?

Comment: Can you do something like this? Create two render targets `rt1` and `rt2`. Set `currentRT = rt1` and `prevRT = rt2`. In your render loop, render to `currentRT`. Then pass `currentRT` and `prevRT` to your subtraction shader and render to the screen. Then swap the render targets.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley! It worked to some degree, it now uses the previous frame in the subtracion shader, but neither the current or previous are blurred. Just to clarify the process; I first render the `prepComposer`, then `renderer.render(prepScene, camera, currentRT, true)`. Updates the uniforms in the `subtractShader` and lastly render the `subtractComposer`. Then swaps the `currentRT`and `prevRT`. 

Is this correct?

Comment: It is difficult for me to follow you. I expect you can figure it out.

Comment: I am sorry about that, got your suggestion to work though! When rendering `prepScene` to the rendertarget the scene was'nt processed. So I solved it by assigning the `BlurSave.renderTarget` to a new `Scene` with a full-screen quad, and then rendered that scene to the rendertarget. Thanks again!

Comment: Add your suggestion as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post-process your scene with a subtraction shader that uses the difference between the current and previous frames, you can do something like the following:

First create two render targets `rt1 and rt2`. Set `currentRT = rt1` and `prevRT = rt2`.

Then in your render loop, (1) render to `currentRT`, then (2) pass `currentRT` and `prevRT` as uniforms to your subtraction shader and render to the screen, then (3) swap the render targets.

three.js r.70